# Problems with test ads - FB Audience Network

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm, facebook-audience-network, rewardedvideoad

We are trying to show rewarded video ads in our game.

But we are getting this response for the test device/user.

```
{
    code = 1;
    message = "An unknown error has occurred.";
    type = OAuthException;
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/network_ads_common/";
}
```

Here are the logs for the request. (Ad request Parameters)

```
1.AFP = b4e920
2.ALLOWS_ARBITRARY_LOADS = 1
3.APPBUILD = 29
4.APPVERS = 1.0.0
5.BUNDLE = 'my game bundle'
6.COCOS2D = 0
7.COPPA = 0
8. CORE_AFP = 54351be8
9.DENSITY = 2
10.HEIGHT = 0
11.IDFA = 5E57F11A-C663-4FAB-B9F7-DE6F7246AA84
12.IDFA_FLAG = 1
13.LOCALE = en_AM
14. M_BANNER_KEY = 'some key here'
15.MAKE = Apple
16.MEDIATION_SERVICE =
17.MODEL = iPad7,2
18.NETWORK_TYPE = 1
19.NUM_ADS_REQUESTED = 1
20.ORIENTATION = 3
21.OS = iOS
22.OSVERS = 12.1.4
23.PLACEMENT_ID = VID_HD_16_9_15S_APP_INSTALL#my_live_placement_id
24.REQUEST_TIME = 1553694293.090104
25.ROOTED = 1
26.SCREEN_HEIGHT = 768
27.SCREEN_WIDTH = 1024
28.SDK = ios
29.SDK_CAPABILITY = [3,4,5,7,9,10,12,16,17]
30.SDK_VERSION = 5.1.0
31.SESSION_ID = 5268043A-BF88-4B94-A773-833396087D5D
32.SESSION_TIME = 15.50397801399231
33.TEMPLATE_ID = 400
34.TEST_MODE = 1
35.UNITY = 0
36.VOLUME = 0.5
37.WIDTH = 0
```

The platform is iOS. 
Any suggestions about what is going wrong? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same here, don't found solution yet ...